# Pandas Replacing a Null Datetime Value in one df with a Timestamp Value from Another

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Bug?  If so, suggestions on a work around?

I have the following:

```
df1['DecisionDate'].head()
Out[238]: 
ID
RED            2017-02-13 00:00:00
GREEN          2016-07-29 00:00:00
ORANGE         2017-01-26 00:00:00
PURPLE         2016-10-31 00:00:00
YELLOW          NaT
Name: DecisionDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And this:

```
df2['DecisionDate']
Out[239]: 
YELLOW   2014-04-05 00:00:00
Name: DecisionDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now if I try to do this:

```
for ID in df2.index:

    df1.ix[ID,'DecisionDate'] = df2.ix[ID,'DecisionDate']
```

I get this

```
TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

No matter what I try I cannot seem to replace the `pd.NaT` with a timestamp value.

All values in both dataframe are timestamps.  df2 observations are a subset of df1 observations so all values in df2.index are in df1.index.

Am I overlooking something straightforwards?  Or is this a bug?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT

Here is the full traceback.  I'm not good at reading this but maybe it will help in diagnosing:

```
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 141, in __setitem__
    def _slice(self, obj, axis=0, kind=None):

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 533, in _setitem_with_indexer

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 473, in setter
    value = getattr(value, 'values', value).ravel()

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3168, in setitem

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3056, in apply
    align_copy = False

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 668, in setitem
    def _replace_single(self, *args, **kwargs):

  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2265, in _try_coerce_args
    Parameters

TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Comment: I am unable to duplicate.  What versions of Python, Pandas, OS, etc?

Comment: Windows 7.  Python 2.7.13.  Spyder 3.1.4 pandas 0.20.2.

Comment: I am matching on all except Spyder.  I suggest you construct sample data that can be directly copy/pasted to execute.  IE a call to `read_csv`, `read_fwf`, or direct construction of a `DataFrame`  See here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945424/python-pandas-multiply-dataframe-by-weights-that-vary-with-category-in-vectorize/43947807#43947807

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Spyder.

```
for ID in df2.index:

        df1.ix[ID,'DecisionDate'] = df2.ix[ID,'DecisionDate']
```

works.

What I had after the line and commented out was the following:

```
for ID in df2.index:

        df1.ix[ID,'DecisionDate'] = df2.ix[ID,'DecisionDate']# some comment
```

Spyder didn't like the comment hash being right next to the active code.  Instead of taking a single value, `df2.ix[ID,'DecisionDate']# some comment` was transformed into a tuple `(myvalue,)` and I was getting a type error.  As soon as I removed the comment from the line it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem was in identifying the NaT type.
This works:

```
    def identify_null(r):
        x = r['ID']
        X = df2.loc[df2.ID == x]['date'] #collect date from other dataframe
        if type(r['date']) == pd.tslib.NaTType:
            return X #intended value from the other data table
        return r['date']

    df['date'] = df.apply(identify_null, axis=1)
```

EDIT: Previously, I had suggested:
A work around:
Drop the rows with missing values. That is consider notnull:

```
    df2 = df[df.date.notnull()]
```

and consider:

```
    df1 = df[df.date.isnull()]
```

for df1, drop the date column and merge it with the dataset that has the date.

```
    frame = [df1_merged, df2]
    df = pd.concat(frame)
```

Note: Sorry not a very smart answer as I haven't tried much on NaT. But this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks.  We're getting into the ugly workaround zone.  I dealt with the issue in a clunky but fairly elegant way - converted my datetimes enmasse to strings after I had performed all operations on them and before I needed to shuffle them around several dataframes.  REALLY annoying problem in light of the fact that others like @Stephen Raush couldn't replicate.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 Made an edit. If the problem was in identifying pd.NaT (which uses np.isnan but the type is set into a different pandas obj), setting the condition based on type of the data works well. Hope you find this useful.